# Find N-th Word from a Source Using Selenium WebDriver Java

Tags: java, regex, search, selenium-webdriver

I have the following:

```
String line = "London Paris Tokyo Russia Seoul Beijing";
String notCityName = "Russia";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(notCityName);
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
```

I would like to know how do I find the **column number** for "Russia" which in this case can be visually verified as column 4.

How do you locate that "Russia" is the 4-th word in the list above?

What I am looking for is the answer 4 (four), the number.

What is the Java / Selenium code to find this number 4?

Thank you,
Leo

Comment: The only way, that I can think of, is to use `split` on `String line` and split by the space. Now you'll be able to loop the created array and find the index for which `notCityName` sits in

Comment: Thank you, but I forgot to mention:  The String line contains "Washington DC" as well.  Thus, if we use split, it means that the "Washington" and "DC" are separate cities.

Comment: I have to go to meetings right now and won't be back for about an hour

Comment: @IsThisJavaScript, thank you for your help.

Comment: Hmm that is a problem. Is there any way you can compile the `line` so it splits each city/country with a `,` ?

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, use .split() then loop the contents so you can find the index. Add one to the index to get 4 instead of 3

```
String line = "London Paris Tokyo Russia Seoul Beijing";
String notCityName = "Russia";

String[] splitLine = line.split(" ");
for(int i = 0; i < splitLine.length; i++){
  if(splitLine[i].equals(notCityName)) {
    System.out.print(++i);
  }
}
```

Outputs 4. Remove the `++i` and it'll say 3 since array index starts at 0

Answer (score 0):

Your actual question really doesn't have anything to do with Selenium; it's a pure Java question of finding a word within a string. In which case this is a duplicate of any number of other questions.

However, if this is Selenium, I'm curious where `line` is coming from. There are only really two options: it's a string you generate or a it's a string from the website.

1. If it is a string you generate, why don't you instantiate it as an array or list? If it's really in your code as `String line = "London Paris Tokyo Russia Seoul Beijing";`, then make it `List<String> line` or `ArrayList<String> line`? If you're reading it in from an external file, can you not read it as a a CSV?
2. If it is something read off the screen, is it really just one long .getText()? You refer to the line as *"column headers"*, which would lead me to believe it's part of a grid or table. In which case, why can't you read each column one at a time and build an Array or List instead of a flat String?

Comment: It was from a table online (No. 2 above). The problem was to identify the column of the word I was looking for, not finding the word per se.

Comment: @smalltownstory, in which case you should read in each of the locations, one per `<td>`, and create an array. Then it's a simple matter of iterating through the array to find Russia. Just remember that arrays are 0-indexed so you'll have to add 1 to the index value to get the right answer